# math formula wrong integration

Tags: python, math

`the formula im trying to integrate. https://prnt.sc/OMvgREyExFjd

in the task if y = 1.4 and f = 0.5 then the answer is appx 0.28991
but i get 0.608....

where did i make it wrong i rewrote code 3 times and every single time i got different answer.

```
import math
y = 1.4
f = 0.5
a = (1-((1+(2*y)/(y-1)-(f**2)-(math.sqrt((1+((2*y)/(y-1))-(f**2))**2-(4*(f**2)*((2*y)/(y-1)-1)))))/(2*(f**2)*(((2*y)/(y-1))-1))))**(y/(y-1))
print(a)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok. let me delete it

Comment: Beside the point, but isn't that a gamma (`γ`), not y?

Comment: i didnt find gamma thats why i used Y instead of it

Comment: Do you mean integrate or implement? I suspect the second. My tip is to split into sub-terms that are easier to read and debug. Also, pre-define common terms, such as `2*gamma / (gamma - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the picture you provided, your formula IS well implemented, in the sense that it gives the answer P(phi=0.5, 1.4) = 0.608236. (I coded it up in Python and Mathematica to test it).

What is that you are trying to accomplish here? Perhaps your text formula is wrong in the first place? Without much background, I can tell that your formula is something like

P = Pt(1 - x)^(g/(g-1))

where x is one of the roots of a 2nd order polynomial. Is this a thermodynamic/efficiency problem? Perhaps you need to revisit how you obtained P. Looks like an adiabatic process may not have been correctly integrated...

Comment: the formula i am trying to implement is this: https://prnt.sc/OMvgREyExFjd
according to the question it must be around 0.289 ( https://prnt.sc/_v3d5wMfNrNO ) not 0.608

Comment: Books have errors sometimes :) What's the textbook? There may be some errata file flying around...

Comment: I can also confirm the result of JustLearning and you - implementing independently from your formula graphics.

Comment: thanks guys. i believed the book a more than myself and stood on this code for 2 hours. thanks for helping im relieved